# Swift: animate button up with swipe up? change direction that safari comes in from?

Tags: ios, swift, uianimation

Im working in Swift and I am going to set up my view like this:

[image]

When the user swipes up, I want to animate the top image view and text so they move up WITH the swipe in the moments before the app is exited to go to Safari (the swipe gesture triggers opening a url).

I am trying to figure out the cleanest way to accomplish this - I am planning on simply animating up the image view using UIAnimations, however Im not sure the animation will go through all the way before the app is exited. Is there another way to achieve this effect?

I also need to know if it is possible to change the direction that the app "switches out" to Safari- by default, Safari comes in from the right. It does not look as good this way and Id really like Safari to segue in from the bottom - Can I force external apps to segue in from a different direction?

Comment: I must be missing something.  Why not have the swipe gesture trigger your animation, then launch Safari in the animation completion block?

Comment: I am going to do that, however I want to know if I can alter the direction that Safari segues in from (i.e. not from the right)